# Convert from enum to string and back using explicit operator casting

Tags: c#, enums, operator-keyword, explicit

I want to convert from an enum to a string using explicit operator casting logic. Why am I getting a “User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type”? It should be possible to do that since the types are sub-types of the enclosing types.

```
class ConversionDemo{

    public enum Letters { A, B, C };

    public String LetterName { get; }

    public void DoWork(ConversionDemo.Letters letter) {
        this.LetterName = (String)letter;
    }

    public static explicit operator String(ConversionDemo.Letters letter) {
        if (letter == Letters.A) { return "A"; }
        if (letter == Letters.B) { return "B"; }
        if (letter == Letters.C) { return "C"; }
        return "?";
    }

    public static explicit operator ConversionDemo.Letters(String s) {
        if (s == "A") { return Letters.A; }
        if (s == "B") { return Letters.B; }
        return Letters.C;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this C#? Please tag all posts with the language you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define conversions for a enum type. You can only define it for classes or structs. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476(v=vs.71).aspx).

So, an alternative for what you need can be change your conversions and define it as extension methods:

```
public enum Letters { A, B, C };

public static class ConversionExtensions
{
    public static string ConvertToString(this Letters letter)
    {
        if (letter == Letters.A) { return "A"; }
        if (letter == Letters.B) { return "B"; }
        if (letter == Letters.C) { return "C"; }
        return "?";
    }

    public static Letters ConvertToLetter(this string s)
    {
        if (s == "A") { return Letters.A; }
        if (s == "B") { return Letters.B; }
        return Letters.C;
    }
}
```

And then, you can use the extension methods for conversion:

```
// Declare a enum type object.
Letters firstLetter = Letters.A;

// Convert from enum to string.
string strLetter = firstLetter.ConvertToString();

// Convert back from string to enum.
Letters secondLetter = strLetter.ConvertToLetter();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The "enclosing type" is the actual class or struct that the method is declared in and does not apply to any [nested types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx).  So the operators would have to be defined inside the definition of `String` or `Letters`.  Neither of which is possible.

This question deals with a similar issue: [explicit conversion operator error when converting generic lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971925/explicit-conversion-operator-error-when-converting-generic-lists).