# Can someone explain this bit of MVVM code

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I am trying out this MVVM thing and am going off a blog post by John Shews ([A Minimal MVVM UWP App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/)). I think I understand most of what's going on except for a little piece in the `NotificationBase` file.

Here is the part I'm having trouble understanding.

```
public class NotificationBase<T> : NotificationBase where T : class, new()
{
    protected T This;

    public static implicit operator T(NotificationBase<T> thing) { return thing.This; }

    public NotificationBase(T thing = null)
    {
        This = (thing == null) ? new T() : thing;
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a line by line description of this code? There's a bunch of stuff going on that I can't quite get a handle on.

Comment: first: [class inheriting another class and defining specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786774/in-c-sharp-what-does-where-t-class-mean) second: [implicit vs explicit castings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971925/explicit-conversion-operator-error-when-converting-generic-lists) and third, if required, [ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these concepts are explained very well in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes).

With that out of the way, I'll try to explain each line, below:

```cs
public class NotificationBase<T> : NotificationBase where T : class, new()
```

Declares a new class named `NotificationBase<T>` which has a single generic type parameter (`T`). It derives from the class `NotificationBase` (the non-generic version). It has two constraints on the type parameter; it must be a `class` (i.e. reference type, not an enum or other integral type), and it must have a visible empty constructor (as dictated by the `new()` constraint).

```cs
protected T This;
```

Declares a [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) field named `This`. You can use the field in instances of this class and in derived objects.

```cs
public static implicit operator T(NotificationBase<T> thing) { return thing.This; }
```

Adds an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) from `NotificationBase<T>` to `T`, such that you can do the following (example):

> ```cs
> NotificationBase<string> myWrappedString = new NotificationBase<string>("Heya");
> string myString = myWrappedString;
> // implicit conversion is supported due to the implicit operator declared above.
> ```

```cs
public NotificationBase(T thing = null)
{
    This = (thing == null) ? new T() : thing;
}
```

Declares a public constructor, such that you can create instances of `NotificationBase<T>`. If the input is `null`, the constructor will just `new` up a thing of type `T` (whatever it is, as long as it has an empty constructor). A [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (`predicate ? then : else`) is used to make the code compact and readable when assigning to the `This` field.

Comment: Probably he doesn't understand the MVVM context and does very well understand the single language elements like Generics.

Comment: @UweKeim the person said: "Can anyone give me a *line by line description* of this code? There's a bunch of stuff going on that I can't quite get a handle on.". I just assumed that it's what they wanted :-).